# How to get a random permutation of integers inside range without permuting the whole array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, permutation

Say I have a very long array, and I want to return a random permutation of a subset of that array... How do I do that without having to permute the whole array?

The way I can think of is

```
import numpy
N = 10000000 # total number of elements
n = 20 # number of elements that I am interested in getting from the permutation
x = numpy.random.permutation(numpy.arange(N))[:n] # this permutes the whole array
```

Basically, I need to select `n` unique integers greater than or equal to `0` and less than `N`...

I know it is easy to do that explicitly, but is there a numpy way or a function in any module in python that works like `randperm(N,n)` in MATLAB?

So far, I've only found python examples that are variations of what I described up here.

Comment: [`numpy.random.choice()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Comment: Given that the source array is large, and you do not know how many elements are in your required range, then using an adaptation of [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) would likely suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a lazy generator for the very long array, it might be more efficient to use the standard [`random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

```py
N = 10000000

import numpy as np
%timeit np.random.choice(range(N), size=20, replace=False)
# 1.52 s ± 20.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit np.random.choice(np.arange(N), size=20, replace=False)
# 376 ms ± 3.95 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

import random
%timeit np.array(random.sample(range(N), k=20))
# 19 µs ± 86.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So, if you have a generator/iterator rather than an in-memory array, the `random` module can be significantly faster.

However, if you are specifically interested in getting `k` numbers between `0` and `N`, the easiest thing is probably to use something like

```
%timeit np.random.choice(N, size=20, replace=False)
# 410 ms ± 12.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

although it is slightly slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.random.choice(arr, size=20, replace=False)` assuming you already have `arr`.